# What could have caused this damage?

Tags: troubleshooting, extruder, nozzle, dremel-3d45

My Dremel 3D45 stopped the extrusion. I removed the nozzle thinking about it was clogged. But still it didn't solve. Also the nozzle was harder to remove than usual.

So I removed the bottom cover and I found this:

[image]

[image]

It seems the heater is completely burned and messed up.
Unfortunately the replacement parts are hard to find.

**I'm wondering what could have caused this damage**.
I didn't run the nozzle over 220 °C (usually 195 °C) and the printer has less than 250 hours of working time.

It was just a defect? Or could I have prevented it?

Comment: Can you further explain what is shown in the picture? Is it the filament that surrounds the heater block?

Comment: @kosteklvp not sure what it is. But I don't think is the filament. In the last 50-60 hours I only extruded white PLA. And the nozzle is screwed inside the bottom of this "stuff" (see the new picture). I think it's this part: https://cdn3.volusion.com/qabo2.bcf6q/v/vspfiles/photos/BSH-1619PB2277-2.jpg

Comment: @kosteklvp I mean, I don't think the filament could/should go there

Comment: There could be a leak between the heat break and heater block. You can check, if this is filament, by heating it up and seeing if it melts.

Comment: Search aliexpress.com  - there's a great chance of finding a suitable replacement, just takes 2-12 weeks to arrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say that the nozzle removal was harder than normal it can be concluded that it has been removed before.

Looking at the hotend when new,
[image]
it evidently looks as if filament has been entrapped onto and on top of the heater block.

It could be that in a prior attempt to remove or replace the nozzle, the heat break has come loose or un-tightened as such that molten filament leaked on top of the heater block.

This hypothesis is more likely in this case than filament that has been ricochetted back from the nozzle opening back to the cavity containing the hot end (I recently experienced this latter issue on an Ultimaker destroying the core...).

Comment: Is it possible I broke it by myself?

Comment: Do you recommend to change this part only, and see.... before change all the extruder (core?) ? It's very expensive and I'm afraid they don't cover this parts with the warranty.

Comment: @Mark It is very hard to answer your question, my assessment is an honest interpretation of the results I see based on my own experience. If you have broken it or not can best be answered by you, but yes, it is a possibility the heat break has been accidentally been unscrewed. Frankly, I would never recommend a Dremel 3D printer, too price for the quality they offer, but their other tools are great. I don't think this is covered by the warranty. Even if there are no spares available, it should be doable to create a makeshift hotend replacement from other parts.